# How make repeat custom field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have to make repeat custom field in wordpress but I don't know how to make it. I had google on stack exchange wordpress development and stack overflow. There are some answers but I can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe you need a repeat field to get information from the users just like booking forms or contact forms. In WordPress there so many plugins available that do this thing. You can use it those plugins. I am adding one of them here so you can get an idea.

Contact form 7 https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ which is used by more than 5+ million sites.

You can use this addons https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-repeatable-fields/ to make a repeat field as many you want.

By using Contact form 7 you can send mail to admin as well as users in the format you want.

**Note:you can also customized it if you want.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have to make it without any plugin by myself. I want to make it like if I have one input field and I want another input field, so I just click on button and then I get another input field and so on.

Comment: Hi check this link https://codepen.io/digvijayad/pen/RegBxg